# How to hide JSP files in TOMCAT webapp folder

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We have done a COLLEGE MANAGEMENT PROJECT in JSP using TOMCAT webserver.But,we panicked that some users at that college may stole the programming code.But we are unable to set our password to the system, because it is used by many faculty in that college.
How can i hide my actual code ?
Can anyone help me..please..

Comment: you CANNOT prevent it unless you can have network level security here, anyone can decompile your servlet and get java code out of it, views are fine to share assuming they just act as template, and obfuscuate the comiled classes to make it little more harder

Comment: Do you want a folder level lock ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yes, ofcourse we need folder level lock.But if we lock the folder which contains code,will that code works ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing all your business level programming in JSP: Don't worry, nobody will want to have it, other than as an example of how to not do it.

JSPs in tomcat's webapps folder are compiled and delivered as HTML to the browser. All your code will be gone anyway, replaced by the actual HTML code that it's supposed to generate.

And if you don't want them to be able to be requested directly (e.g. http://www.example.com/showSomething.jsp) you can put them into your WEB-INF folder, but you'll have to do some request forwarding internally. How to do this is beyond this simple answer as you don't give any indication of the frameworks that you're using.